# Why does this 2D array not output values properly?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm a beginner to coding and I'm very out of my depth with my latest programming assignment.

What my program should do:

1. Take input from a file that holds 10,000 integers and read the ints into an array.
2. Run the array through 4 sorting algorithms: bubble sort, insertion sort, selection sort and count sort.
3. Track the amount of swaps, comparisons, and time taken for the algorithms to sort the data.
4. Generate a table that presents the data neatly.

Note that the array must be run through each algorithm 5 times, the first time with the first 2000 values stored in the file, then 4000 and so on until the whole file is stored there. This is to compare the swaps, comparisons and time taken between each iteration of the array.

My solution is:

- Use data structures to compile the info I need. (admittedly I don't know too much about data structures; I may have screwed up here).
- Used an array of function pointers to run each algorithm, which I set up in main. It... looks like it should be working? And yet, nothing after bubbleSort is printing correctly.
- Use 2d arrays to store the data, with [i] representing the index location for the algorithm function and [j] being the iteration of N (the upper limit).

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> //used to calculate time taken to run each function

struct triple bubbleSort(int[], int);
struct triple insertionSort(int[], int);
struct triple selectionSort(int[], int);
struct triple countSort(int[], int);

int readFileData(int[], int);
int findMax(int[], int);
int findMin(int[], int);
void makeTable(int[][5], int[][5], double[][5]);


//this data structure will carry the values of all comps, swaps, and time taken
struct triple { 
    int comps;
    int swaps;
    double timeCalc;
};

FILE* fp; //points to file1.txt
int arrA[10000]; //will hold the values read from fp
clock_t start, end; //calculates time taken by each sorting alg

int main() {
    int limit = 2000;
    //array of function pointers for each sorting alg
    struct triple (*funp[4])(int[], int) = { bubbleSort, insertionSort, selectionSort, countSort };
    int swaps[4][5]; //2d array for swaps
    int comps[4][5];
    double timeCalc[4][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //for all sorting algs
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 && limit <= 10000; j++) { //for all iterations of N
            readFileData(arrA, limit); //reads file data from 0 - current size
            struct triple data = funp[i](arrA, limit); //calls correct sorting alg per value of i
            swaps[i][j] = data.swaps; //updates data in swap array
            comps[i][j] = data.comps; //updates data in comparison array
            timeCalc[i][j] = data.timeCalc; //updates time in timeCalc

            limit += 2000; //increases val of size

        }

    }
    makeTable(swaps, comps, timeCalc);
}

int readFileData(int arrA[], int limit) {
    fopen_s(&fp, "file1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File not found at specified location");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int read = 0; read < limit; read++) { //reads every line of file1 until limit is reached
            char buffer[8]; //temporarily holds each int val
            fgets(buffer, 8, fp); //reads each line into buffer[]
            arrA[read] = atoi(buffer); //converts char to int + stores in arrA
            //printf("%d values of ArrA: %d\n", read + 1, arrA[read]);

        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

void makeTable(int swaps[][5], int comps[][5], double timeCalc[][5]) {
    printf("Using data from file1.txt\n\n\n");
    printf("\n-------\nBubbleSort()\n-------\n\n");
    printf("N%-15sSwaps%-15sComparisons%-15sTime Taken\n", "", "", "");
    int limit = 2000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%-15d%-22d%-26d%lf\n", limit, swaps[0][i], comps[0][i], timeCalc[0][i]);
        limit += 2000;
    }
    limit = 2000;
    printf("\n-------\nInsertionSort()\n-------\n\n");
    printf("N%-15sSwaps%-15sComparisons%-15sTime Taken\n", "", "", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%-15d%-22d%-26d%lf\n", limit, swaps[1][i], comps[1][i], timeCalc[1][i]);
        limit += 2000;
    }
    limit = 2000;
    printf("\n-------\nSelectionSort()\n-------\n\n");
    printf("N%-15sSwaps%-15sComparisons%-15sTime Taken\n", "", "", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%-15d%-22d%-26d%lf\n", limit, swaps[2][i], comps[2][i], timeCalc[2][i]);
        limit += 2000;
    }
    limit = 2000;
    printf("\n-------\nCountSort()\n-------\n\n");
    printf("N%-15sSwaps%-15sComparisons%-15sTime Taken\n", "", "", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%-15d%-22d%-26d%lf\n", limit, swaps[3][i], comps[3][i], timeCalc[3][i]);
        limit += 2000;
    }
}

struct triple bubbleSort(int arrA[], int size) {
    struct triple ret;
    int i, k, temp;
    start = clock();
    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1 - k; i++) {
            ++ret.comps;
            if (arrA[i] > arrA[i + 1]) {
                //out of order so swap
                temp = arrA[i];
                arrA[i] = arrA[i + 1];
                arrA[i + 1] = temp;
                ++ret.swaps;
            }
        } //end inner i for
    } //end outer k for
    end = clock();
    ret.timeCalc = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //printf("Swaps: %d\tComparisons: %d\tTime taken: %f", comp, swap, timeCalc);
    return ret;
}



struct triple insertionSort(int arrA[], int size) {
    printf("is: test ");
    struct triple ret;
    ret.comps = 0;
    ret.swaps = 0;
    int i, j, curr;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        curr = arrA[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && curr < arrA[j]; j--) { 
            ret.comps++;
            arrA[j + 1] = arrA[j];
            ret.swaps++;
        }
        if (i != j + 1) // if not at the correct position already
            arrA[j + 1] = curr;
    }
    end = clock();
    ret.timeCalc = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Insertion sort: %d %d %lf\n", ret.swaps, ret.comps, ret.timeCalc);
    return ret;
} //return



struct triple selectionSort(int arrA[], int size) {
    printf("ss: test");
    int i, j, min, temp;
    struct triple ret;
    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        ++ret.comps;
        //find next smallest
        for (j = min + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arrA[min] > arrA[j]) {
                min = j;
            }
        } // end j for loop
        //swap values at locations i and min, if i != min
        if (i != min) {
            temp = arrA[i];
            arrA[i] = arrA[min];
            arrA[min] = temp;
            ++ret.swaps;
        }
    } 
    end = clock();
    ret.timeCalc = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return ret;
}

int findMax(int arrA[], int size) {
    //use fp to read through array
    //maxVal = 0; -> if arrA[i] > arrA[i+1] -> maxVal = arrA[i]
    //return maxVal
    int maxVal = 0;
    fopen_s(&fp, "file1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not find file1.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            char buffer[6];
            fgets(buffer, 6, fp);
            arrA[i] = atoi(buffer);
            if (arrA[i] > arrA[i + 1]) {
                maxVal = arrA[i];
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("maxVal is %d", maxVal);
    }


}

int findMin(int arrA[], int size) {
    int minVal = 0;
    fopen_s(&fp, "file1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not find file1.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            char buffer[6];
            fgets(buffer, 6, fp);
            arrA[i] = atoi(buffer);
            if (arrA[i] < arrA[i + 1]) {
                minVal = arrA[i];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("minval is %d", minVal);
}

// sort an array of integers using countSort algorithm from 0 to maxVal
struct triple countSort(int arrA[], int size)
    {
    printf("cs: test");
    struct triple ret;
        int i, value, count, maxVal, minVal;
        maxVal = findMax(arrA, size);
        minVal = findMin(arrA, size);
        int freqSize = maxVal + 1;
        int* freq = (int*)calloc(freqSize, sizeof(int));
        int* arrB = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
        // check if memory was allocated, if not exit
        if (!freq || !arrB) {
            printf("Memory not allocated - Exiting \n");
        }
        else {
            start = clock();
            // calloc will initialise arrays to 0
            // count frequencies
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                ++freq[arrA[i]];
            }
            // add <= to freq[]
            for (i = 1; i < freqSize; i++) {
                freq[i] = freq[i] + freq[i - 1];
            }
            // place values from arrA[] into arrB[]; update freq[]
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                value = arrA[i]; //value to sort
                count = freq[value]; //<= freq of value
                arrB[count - 1] = value; //place value in arrB
                --freq[value]; //decrement freq[]
            } //get next value in arrA
            //write back sorted values to arrA[] now that sorting finished
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                arrA[i] = arrB[i];
            }
            free(freq);
            free(arrB);
        }
        end = clock();
        ret.timeCalc = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        return ret;
    }
```

The sorting algorithms themselves should be fine, but I notice that any print statements I put in insertionSort() onwards don't get output to the console.  We were given permission to use our lecturer's own sample algorithms so there shouldn't be anything wrong with the algorithms themselves. The only one I've adjusted is countSort() to take min values as well as max values, and I've made new functions to collect that data. I've put in some print statements and nothing from insertion sort onwards seems to be working properly, although the console still outputs the table.

I'm sorry I know my code is very messy, especially the makeTable() function. Ideally I'll figure out how to write this all to a .csv file or something. Generating an organised table in the default VS compiler is an alignment nightmare. Lesson learned.

Thanks for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: `int limit = 2000;` should be inside the outer loop. Right now, the inner loop terminates when it hits the maximum limit, then the next iteration of the outer loop is not resetting it. That means all subsequent iterations bypass the inner loop.

Comment: As a side-note, re-reading the file constantly is a bit overkill. Why not just slurp its contents into another array and copy that when you want to perform each new test? That makes your `findMin` and `findMax` functions much simpler. Right now, there's too much code duplication, meaning if you ever wanted to change the file format or parsing rules, it would be a nightmare. Your line buffer in these functions is unreasonably small. Your program will also break if the file contains negative values.

Comment: You have several function that do not return a value in all cases or at all. Turn up the warnings in your compiler and fix them.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/KeGYr4fdj) is a [mre] that you could have constructed yourself to investigate the issue. Note how all the unnecessary stuff is removed, making the problem _much_ clearer. When you found that your print statements were not being output, it narrowed the problem to either 1) the program crashes; or 2) the function is not called. But the program outputs a table and exits properly, so that really leaves only option 2. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/o4fGWoY9b) is the fix mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: `struct triple ret;` does NOT initialize the bytes of the memory. You're starting with an undefined values of `++ret.comps;` and the other counter...

Comment: Any question about performance which doesn't mention the compiler and compiler options used is unclear on the most fundamental level of all. If you are benchmarking with optimizations disabled, this whole program is pointless.

Comment: Another issue is that you shouldn't count the number of comparisons and clock the functions at the same time. The counting itself adds overhead, so that the function with most comparisons seems much more inefficient than it actually is. Use `#ifdef` compiler switches to run the function with or without comparisons, or alternatively make 2 different functions of each kind.

Comment: @paddy Re-reading the file might be a way to ensure that the cache is flushed and "cold"? Running this over and over on the same data on something like an x86 is questionable benchmarking.

Comment: In general, benchmarking is _hard_ and not even veterans get it right... so this is a very bad exercise for beginners, unless the teacher can hand out a framework source with "your function here" places.